# Drawing furniture

Tags: drawing, cad

I need to find software to draw things like furniture or other home stuff in a Mac, something similar to AutoCad, but much more simple - in 2D.

I am not expert in drawing, so something we can load the object from the toolbar or similar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Sweet Home 3D](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Sweet_Home_3D), it has both 2D and 3D mode and a lot of furniture built-in.

[image]

Comment: Looks good. A more direct link is http://www.sweethome3d.com

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [SketchUp](https://www.sketchup.com/) (formerly Google Sketchup)

I've been playing around with it for some design work I've been doing for 3D Printing.

There is also a [large community](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/) which makes models available.

Hope that helps.

Brian

Comment: SketchUp is good, but the question asks for 2D.

Comment: there's nothing that says you have to use the z-axis in sketchup.  Just stick to a single plane.  Also, I don't believe the original post mentioned that restriction (I just checked, it was edited in after I made my response)